# How to make modules from golang.org appear with semver tags in my go.mod?

Tags: go, go-modules

In my `go.mod` file. 
I wanna change versioning about modules from golang.org.

they have commit date and hash after version.

I'm using go mod, So I have `go.mod` file in my workspace.
My `go.mod` is as follow.

```
module myproject

go 1.12.6

require (
    github.com/lib/pq v1.1.1
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190701094942-4def268fd1a4
    golang.org/x/image v0.0.0-20190523035834-f03afa92d3ff
)
```

like this.

golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190701094942-4def268fd1a4 -> golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0

How to change it?

I think they don't have major versioning officialy.
as a result, I wanna simplify my `go.mod` file

Comment: If they don't have a tagged version, you can't. You can only specify a version that actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

The versioning for a Go module is determined by the author of that module, not the consumer.

(You can use a `replace` directive to remap versions arbitrarily, but then nobody could use *your* module without doing that same remapping — it wouldn't simplify anything for anybody.)